# Is better to use one big kernel or cuda streams?

Tags: cuda

what is better? I need to process data in several steps and it appears to me that I've 2 options:
1) use one big kernel
2) use streams with one kernel for each step

There is some latency before a kernel is executed, but does it really matter in this case? Is latency for a big kernel same as sum of latencies for several smaller kernels?

Are there any advantages one way compared to the other one?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch latency for a kernel on a Fermi card is on the order of 10us, so nothing to worry about. It makes sense -- to render a scene in a game, one has to run many different shaders (which are kernels).

A kernel has to read the data that it will process from global memory and write the results back to global memory. So each separate kernel implies that full read/write cycle. You may be able to speed things up if you are able to chain multiple steps together in a big kernel, still bracketed by a single read/write cycle.

As an example, if you need to perform operations A, B and C, chaining them might give you READ - A - B - C - WRITE while separate kernels would give you READ - A - WRITE - READ - B - WRITE - READ - C - WRITE.

Remember, even if you run even a single kernel, you can still keep your code readable by breaking the separate steps out to separate device functions.

Comment: Big kernels also have big register footprints which can have a significant effect on performance.

Comment: I haven't checked but, in theory, if variables are not shared between the steps in a chain, the compiler should be able to keep reusing registers so that total register usage only equals that of the step that uses the most. Even so, it's a good point and shared memory usage should probably be considered in the same way. In other words, it's possible that if the resource usage of one step in the chain is much higher than the other steps, it may keep occupancy down for the other steps, and so it would be better to run it separately.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use device function and one big kernel.